# How to access json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-maps, laravel-5

I'm getting google response in Json format. when I decode and print the output it works perfectly. Like this

```
print_r($output);
```

But when I trying to access the single parameter of the array it's not working.

```
print_r($output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
```

It gives this error.

> "message": "Undefined offset: 0",
>   Code:

```
       public function mapdata(Request $request){
        $address = $request->name;
        $formattedAddress = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
        $response = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddress.'&sensor=true_or_false&key=APIKEY); 
        $output = json_decode($response);
        //print_r($output);
        print_r($output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
      }
```

Output:

```
  stdClass Object
  (
 [results] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [address_components] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Melbourne
                                [short_name] => Melbourne
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => colloquial_area
                                        [1] => locality
                                        [2] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Victoria
                                [short_name] => VIC
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [long_name] => Australia
                                [short_name] => AU
                                [types] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => country
                                        [1] => political
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [formatted_address] => Melbourne VIC, Australia
                [geometry] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [bounds] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [northeast] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => -37.5112737
                                        [lng] => 145.5125288
                                    )

                                [southwest] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => -38.4338593
                                        [lng] => 144.5937418
                                    )

                            )

                        [location] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [lat] => -37.8136276
                                [lng] => 144.9630576
                            )

                        [location_type] => APPROXIMATE
                        [viewport] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [northeast] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => -37.5112737
                                        [lng] => 145.5125288
                                    )

                                [southwest] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [lat] => -38.4338593
                                        [lng] => 144.5937418
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [place_id] => ChIJ90260rVG1moRkM2MIXVWBAQ
                [types] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => colloquial_area
                        [1] => locality
                        [2] => political
                    )

            )

     )

   [status] => OK
   )
```

Comment: Show us the result of `print_r($output);`

Comment: I have added the result of print_r($output);  @HTMHell

Comment: try step by step. print_r($output->results) and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$output->results[0]` is not always set. You want to make sure it's set before trying to access it:

```
if (isset($output->results[0])) {
    print_r($output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
} else {
    // what happens if $output->results[0] is not set
}
```